# Wordpress loop multiple orderby query with Types toolset

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I've created a "stores" custom post type and on the page I order it by title:
`$args = array( 'post_type' => 'store','posts_per_page' => 100, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => "ASC" );`

I'm using the [Types toolset](https://wp-types.com/) and I've created a field for the admin to add the state in two letter form (CA, NY, TX...).
I am trying to modify my loop to not only order by state, but also order by title and I'm not sure how to accomplish that. I looked around and it appears I can make the orderby parameter an array. Below it my code:

```
$state_code = types_render_field("state-code", array());
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'store',
    'posts_per_page' => 100, 
    'orderby' => array(
        $state_code => 'ASC',
        'title' => 'ASC',
    ),
);
```

Am I able to order it in the following hierarchy?: 1) state code alphabetical order (AK, AL, AR....), then by 2) title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you created the custom field using wp-Type then you would have to use `wpcf-state-code`

```
$state_code = types_render_field("state-code", array());
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'store',
    'posts_per_page' => 100, 
    'orderby' => array( 'ASC' => 'DESC', 'meta_value' => 'ASC' )
    'meta_key' => 'wpcf-state-code',
);
```

This should work, let me know.

Comment: This worked! Thank you. You forgot a comma at the end of the `orderyby` key so that threw me off for a little bit. Thank you.